# -include directive should ignore errors. But make stops because of an error

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html#Include):***

> If you want `make` to simply ignore a makefile which does not exist
>   or cannot be remade, with no error message, use the `-include` directive
>   instead of `include`, like this:
>
> -include FILENAMES...
>
> This acts like `include` in every way except that there is no error
>   (not even a warning) if any of the FILENAMES (or any prerequisites of
>   any of the FILENAMES) do not exist or cannot be remade.

***Given the following makefile:***

```make
$(shell rm -rf x foo)

-include mkfile


all: ;

mkfile : x ;

x : foo ;

.INTERMEDIATE : x
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo', needed by 'x'.  Stop.
```

Well, shouldn't Make just **ignore** this error, as we use a `-include` (not `include`) directive, per the documentation above?

Comment: No it shouldn't. Remove `-` in `-include` and you'll see the difference.

Comment: "Differnece"? They both fail.

Where the quote above reads: "except that there is no error (not even a warning) if any of the FILENAMES (or any prerequisites of any of the FILENAMES) do not exist or cannot be remade".

Again, "no error"!

Comment: Except "No such file or directory" error produced by non-`-` include. `-` suppresses error of include itself. Everything else have nothing to do with include.

Comment: A simple proof. A makefile that has `-include mkfile`, where 1)`mkfile` is out-of-date 2)recipe for `mkfile` is `false`. Make a) Does **not** report error. b)Make terminates with exit-status: 0.

Comment: Okay, I'm not entitled to argue. It works exactly as it should. Out of date doesn't matter here. It appears you expect `include` to be something it isn't.

Comment: Make interprets '-include' to ignore **ANY** errors. That may include errors to rebuild those makefiles, either because Make does not find a rule to build them, or make finds a rule, but the recipe - actually executed for them - failed by the shell, such as the `false` recipe, or any other failing recipe you could think of. Proof of that, is that makefile, I proposed in the comment above, or **any** makefile you could think of, that illustrates such an example.

Answer (score 2):

```console
make: *** No rule to make target 'foo', needed by 'x'.  Stop.
```

> Shouldn't `make` just **ignore** this error, as we use a `-include` (not `include`) directive, per the documentation above?

**No!** Your interpretation of the documentation is wrong.

---

The use of `-` in `-include` will **ONLY** ignore any **files** that succeed it, i.e. come after it. It will **NOT** ignore any file!

You have chosen to take part of the documentation out and build your interpretation on it.

> there is no error (not even a warning) if any of the FILENAMES (or any prerequisites of any of the FILENAMES) do not exist or cannot be remade.

The above quote **ONLY** applies to files that succeed `-include` as in

> -include FILENAMES...

it **does not** apply to every and any files.

---

## Demonstration of `-` in `include`

To demonstrate this we can take a simple example as

```make
$(shell rm -rf mkfile)

-include mkfile

all: 
    echo '$@'

.PHONY: all
```

In this instance either before, or at least on `make`'s second pass, the file `mkfile` does not exist. If we were to execute this, the output would be

```console
$ make
echo 'all'
all
```

Here `make` has ignored the fact that `mkfile` does not exist and has continued processing the `makefile` without warning or error. **This is exactly what the documentation states.**

If instead we removed the `-` before `include` and so had a `makefile` like

```make
$(shell rm -rf mkfile)

include mkfile

all: 
    echo '$@'

.PHONY: all
```

Executing this would produce the output

```console
$ make
makefile:3: mkfile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'mkfile'.  Stop.
```

Now `make` has stopped because there is an error, the file `mkfile` does not exist and we haven't used `-include`.